# Chrome ThreeJS texture

Tags: google-chrome, three.js

I'm new in TreeJS, 
I have a problem with the textures when I use the Chrome browser version 23.0.1271.95 m, in practice it did not load correctly and I get this error:

**Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://localhost:8181/images/texture1.jpg".** 
**Three.js 458**

```
 var terrainGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3);
 var terrainTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/texture1.jpg");
 var terrainMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: terrainTexture}); 
 var terrain = new THREE.Mesh(terrainGeometry, terrainMaterial);
 scene.add(terrain);
```

The same problem does not occur if you use Firefox instead where the textures are correctly loaded.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This might also be a problem of your web server. Maybe the MIME type for `.jpg` is not set to `image/jpeg`?

Comment: Thank you Matthias,
I solved my problem, I changed:
**terrainMaterial THREE.MeshBasicMaterial var = new ({map: terrainTexture })** with **var terrainMaterial= new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: terrainTexture });** and so it go! :)

Comment: I noticed, however, that the problem is whenever I load a texture using Chrome, it happens the same problem with the models Collada (. Dae) and the cubemap. The server is configured properly and he is not the problem.
As with Firefox everything works. I'm using version 53 ThreeJS.